# Podio forbidden error when updating an item

Tags: python, podio

I'm trying to automate the creation of new instances of an app in Podio using python. Creating new instances works fine but one of the fields is a category field and if the category option being passed in doesn't exists then the creation fails. Also I can get the list of available category options to check and see if it will fail beforehand.

I'd like to update the category field to include the new options but when I try I get an error: 
`The app with id XXX does not have the right update on item with id YYY`. 
The app is being accessed using app authentication and the item is part of the app. Also members are allowed to edit items on the settings page.

I tried using the client.Item.update() method that the python API provides:

```
client.Item.update(8491734, allInfo)
```

Where allInfo is a dict containing the entire contents of the category field including the newest category option.

This is a very similar issue: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202650163-Weird-Forbidden-error?page=1#community_comment_360007440892 but users are allowed to edit items in the app.

I'm wondering if it's possible to update a category field in this manner and if not is there another work flow that would allow automatically creating new instances of an app that possibly contains new category options for the category field.

Comment: can you share how did you constructed allInfo?

Comment: I used the get app field method in the podio api (https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-field-22353) and then I appended a new entry to the `options` list inside with the format { status: "", text: "", id: "", color: "" }

Comment: did you try to create a new item using the details from getappfield api, instead of using the same?

Comment: As in creating a new field with the new category option? That could work but there are already lots of instances out there using the old field so if I were to create a new one and delete the old one I'd have to record the states of all existing instances and then update them to the new field. There are around 15,000 currently so that doesn't feel like an elegant solution.

Comment: I didn't meant to create new item in Podio, you have create a new object instead of reusing the same object you got from getappfield api. You can use the same ItemId so that the existing item will be updating.

Comment: Unfortunately that still results in `Authentication as app is not allowed for this method","error":"forbidden"`

Comment: `I'd like to update the category field to include the new options` - please clarify how you do that?

Comment: `client.Item.update(8491734, allInfo)` where the number is the id of the field and allInfo is a json object containing the new category I'd like to add to the list of categories in the field. Previously I tried with allInfo being a json object containing the entire contents of the field including the newest category option but neither option has been allowed.